# In Drupal 8 views, how can I rewrite the output of image field to become a div with this image as a background image?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, view, drupal-8

I have a view to display a content that have an image field, and I need to display this image as a background image of a div so I can apply some CSS on it.

what I tried to do is to rewrite the output of this field using twig to be like this:

```
<div class="page-image" style="background-image: url({{ field_image }});">
</div>
```

the problem is that Drupal strips style attribute so the output will be like this:

```
<div class="page-image">
</div>
```

In D7 I used to fix this kind of issues by overriding the template for the specific field, but I couldn't figure out what is the name of the needed template in D8. when I enabled twig debug it turned out that the field is using the template file `views-view-field.html.twig` which is the default template for all fields in views, but I couldn't find the needed template name for this specific field in this view.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting started with D8 development and was figuring out how views templating works.

You would copy /core/modules/views/templates/views-view-field.html.twig into your theme directory and name the template with the following convention.

views-view-fields--articles-[view machine name]--[view display id].html.twig

I know this after reading this really useful [post](http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a preprocessor solution that I'm using:

In my .theme file I have:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

    if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
        if ($node->field_hero_background_image->entity) {
            $variables['hero_background_image_url'] = file_create_url($node->field_hero_background_image->entity->getFileUri());
        }
    }
}
```

then in my page.html.twig

```
style="background-image: url('{{ hero_background_image_url }}')
```

Comment: Works great, and to get the variable in a node template, just change the function to ´THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables)´

Comment: There's no reason to use THEMENAME_preprocess_page here, it's always better to be more precise (as in, be as precise as you need to be).  Reason being is performance ... the page version runs on every page, regardless of whether it's a node or not.  Use THEMENAME_preprocess_node and fetch the already loaded node using $node = $variables['node'];

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'blazy' (https://www.drupal.org/project/blazy) for displaying images. In views then there is an option to display blazy-images as background-images. So you don't have to change the general way for all images.